# c++ flash under linux

Tags: c++, linux, flash

I known how to use flash in my windows c++ application with ActiveX.

But what it the way to do it under linux?

Answer (score 3):

Under Linux, you'll need to load the Flash plugin using [`dlopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen), then use the [plugin API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference) (which the Flash plugin implements) to set up and interact with Flash. If there's a simpler way, I'm not aware of it.

See also [Chromium's Linux plugin notes](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxPlugins) for more on the plugin API.